# Function should count the number of values from 0 to the “max” parameter that are evenly divisible .this divisible function

Tags: python, for-loop, parameters, range

I come across a problem statement to write  a python piece of code to write a function that should count the number of values from 0 to the “max” parameter that are evenly divisible (no remainder) by the “divisor” parameter.

```
def divisible(max, divisor):
    count = 0 # Initialize an incremental variable
    for x in range(max): # Complete the for loop
        if x % divisor == 0:
            count+=1  # Increment the appropriate variable
    return count

print(divisible(100, 10)) # Should be 10
print(divisible(10, 3)) # Should be 4
print(divisible(144, 17)) # Should be 9
```

I wrote above code. I want to know is there any better code or alternative script. pls comment

Comment: Why are you shadowing *max* ?

Answer (score 2):

since you need a count of values for which value%divisor == 0 and it should be between [0, max), where max is not inclusive then what you can do is

just `(max_value-1)//divisor + 1` number of value for which a number is divisible by divisor with no remainder, +1 is for value 0

so your solution should be

```
def divisible(max_value, divisor):
    return (max_value - 1)//divisor + 1
```